# Why don't the admin pages in my Django application reference the right CSS URLs?

Tags: django, django-admin

When I visit the admin pages of my Django application, I notice that they reference CSS at addresses like `admin/css/base.css`. However, I noticed that the admin css files are actually located at addresses such as `media/css/base.css`.

Hence, the CSS does not load in my admin pages. Why is this so? I have tried to manually move the CSS files on my server to accomodate the admin page URLs, but this is unreliable since the CSS URLs referenced in the admin pages are relative (and thus change for every page).

Answer (score 0):

NOTE - My previous answer is deprecated for Django 1.4, as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#django-contrib-admin

If you're using Django 1.4, just point the STATIC_URL setting to the appropriate location, e.g.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

or

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/static/'
```

and your admin static files will be automatically put at STATIC_URL+'admin/'. This is probably why your admin files reference css at /admin/css. The question is why are the actual files located at /media/css - did you manually upload them? Does collectstatic put them there? Try collectstatic and see if it puts the admin/css files in the appropriate location, and then just upload that to the server.

---

/static/admin/css is the default location for your admin css files. Are your settings correct?

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

The above would cause your admin css files to be collected to /static/admin/css when you use the

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

command. If you change it to

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/media/'
```

I would assume the css files would be collected at /static/media/css instead (though I haven't tested this).

Also, why does manually moving the css files not work? Not that I would recommend it (should use python manage.py collectstatic to collect all your static files for you in one consolidated location), but if you moved them to /static/admin/css that should still be what your CSS files are referencing, right?

As a note, you can make the ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX absolute as well. Mine are set to my s3 bucket, e.g.

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = 'https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/static/admin/'
```